# Any tips to access office 365 email via PHP easier?

Tags: php, authentication, outlook, smtp, office365

I been using PHP to access my email from Office 365 but the email it self is from Gabohost (godaddy):

`$mbox = imap_open(   "{outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX"`

Few days ago, Gabohost wrote that they no longer will be allowing "Basic Authentication".
So I've checked online and holy ___ going from 1 line code to 50 to access e-mail seems a lot.

So I just wanted to ask, without using 3rd party tools etc, I REALLY have to create an app on microsoft dev and use pretty chunky codes to access email from now on?
There's no easier way? :/
I only need to be able to Read, delete & move emails (not send).

Thanks a lot in advance guys

Comment: You need to migrate to the [Graph API](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider using the Graph API instead, see [Use the Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-the-api) for more information.

Microsoft has disabled basic auth protocol for POP/IMAP accounts, read more about that in the [Basic Authentication Deprecation in Exchange Online – September 2022 Update - Microsoft Community Hub](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/basic-authentication-deprecation-in-exchange-online-september/ba-p/3609437) article.

Comment: And here I thought this was going to be simple. Definitely considering now using 3rd party tool (Free).
Any suggestions you have for the lightest code to accomplish this using 3rd party tool in PHP? Thanks a lot

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/php?tabs=aad

Answer (score 1):

Yes, no matter what you use - IMAP4, Graph, or anything else - Basic auth is going away. OAuth is the one and only way.